Node position attribute in yFiles for Jupyter
I'm working with the yfiles_jupyter_graphs package in a Jupyter notebook to visualize a graph created with NetworkX.
I want to achieve two things:

Access Node Positions: How can I programmatically access the positions of each node after the graph has been laid out? I would like to retrieve the (x, y) coordinates of all nodes.

Export Graph as GraphML: Is there a way to save the graph directly as a GraphML file using code, without having to manually click "Export to yEd Live" in the widget?


I tried the .get_node_position_mapping() method but the output is:
<function GraphWidget.default_node_position_mapping at 0x0000022797E35670>
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!

(I know the developers of that plugin and also the implementation.)

There is no direct way to get the coordinates from the widget. The coordinates just exist inside the HTML/Javascript widget that renders the graph. The python kernel (and thus the notebook cells) don't have access to them. Currently, the only information you can get back from the widget is the selection state of the items. The mapping function you found is a mapping from your node data to positions to be used as initial input to the widget. It cannot be used to read later values back in since it is an implementation that you may provide to it. You would only be calling your own code or evaluate your bindings.

There is no programmatic way to save the graph after it has been interacted with or laid out. This is a UX and "political" decision. The widget is meant to be used as an interactive widget to conveniently explore the graph. It is not meant to serve as layout engine to programmatically create visualizations. If you are looking to use the yFiles layouts programmatically, you should be looking at using the yFiles libraries, instead. They cover a lot more functionality, but right now can only be evaluated for free, since in contrast to the free widget, these are commercial diagramming libraries.



Thank you for your explanation! I suspected I couldn't do either task, but I wasn't certain.
